# Convert a pdf page to image in itext

Tags: itext

I would like to eliminate/flatten all the hidden layers in one particular pdf page.

One way to do that seems to be to create separate pdf page, add all the design layers and then convert that page to image and add it in the working pdf.

However I am not sure how to convert pdf to image using iText.

Also is it possible to not create layers, but have content over one another like drawing/image such that there is no hidden layer except what we see in page.

Comment: *"I am not sure how to convert pdf to image using itext"* - there is the [*iText PDF Renderer Framework*](https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/technical-notes/itext-pdf-renderer-framework) for that task. I don't think, though, that rendering PDF as image is a *good* way to get rid of layers, you lose much more than just those layers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.Its actually just the cover page that I wish to change.